Does $\mathrm{Tor}^{A[t,t^{-1}]}_1(M \otimes_A A[t,t^{-1}],A) =0?$
I was self studying homological algebra, Tor, Ext etc. My questing is the following.

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $A[t,t^{-1}]$-module. Then does $\mathrm{Tor}^{A[t,t^{-1}]}_1(M \otimes_A A[t,t^{-1}],A) =0?$ (I am taking $A = A[t,t^{-1}]/(t-1)$ as $A[t,t^{-1}]$-module.)

My try is the following: Consider $M \otimes_A A[t,t^{-1}]$ as $(M \otimes_A A[t])_t$ and use that localization is flat and A[t] is a flat A-module.
Thanks in advance.

Is $M$ really a module over $A[t,t^{-1}]$? You don't use the structure. Perhaps you mean a finitely generated $A$-module? Also, how do you make $A$ a module over $A[t,t^{-1}]$? Please add everything to the post itself that is necessary to understand the question.

Your approach only works if $M$ is flat over $A$. I would suggest that you just compute that Tor with a projective resolution of $A$ over $A[t,t^{-1}]$.

@MartinBrandenburg Yes $M$ is a module over $A[t,t^{-1}]$.

So, what have you tried with the projective resolution of the $A[t,t^{-1}]$-module $A$? You can also rely on general facts about $\mathrm{Tor}^R(M,R/r)$ when $r \in R$ is regular (which gives the projective resolution $0 \to R \xrightarrow{r} R \to R/r \to 0$).

@MartinBrandenburg So in this case we have $0\to A[t,t^{-1}] \to A[t,t^{-1}] \to A \to 0$ is a projective resolution of $A$ as a $A[t,t^{-1}]$-module, where the first  map is given by multiplication by $(t-1)$. Now if we consider the long exact sequence of Tor we get $Tor_1^{A[t,t^{-1}]}(M\otimes_A  A[t,t^{-1}],A) $ is $ ker ( M\otimes_A  A[t,t^{-1}] \otimes_{A[t,t^{-1}]} A[t,t^{-1}] \to  M\otimes_A  A[t,t^{-1}] \otimes_{A[t,t^{-1}]} A[t,t^{-1}]) $ which is 0. Is this correct?
